# Pandas: Iterate by two column for each iteration

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know how to iterate a pandas Dataframe with two columns for each iteration?

Say I have

```
   a            b             c            d
 5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2
 4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2
 4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2
 4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2
 5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2
 5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4
```

So something like

```
for x, y in ...:
    correlation of x and y
```

So output will be

```
corr_ab     corr_bc     corr_cd
    0.1         0.3         -0.4
```

Comment: Just do `df.corr()`  ??

Comment: What do you mean by two column iteration?/What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` with indexing for tuples, create dictionary of one element lists with [`Series.corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html) and `f-string`s for columns names and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = {f'corr_{col1}{col2}': [df[col1].corr(df[col2])] 
                        for col1, col2 in zip(df.columns, df.columns[1:])}

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
    corr_ab  corr_bc   corr_cd
0  0.860108  0.61333  0.888523
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.corr` to get the correlation of the dataframe. You then use `mask` to avoid repeated correlations. After that you can stack your new dataframe to make it more readable. Assuming you have data like this

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0  11   6  17   2   3
1   3  12  16  17   5
2  13   2  11  10   0
3   8  12  13  18   3
4   4   3   1   0  18
```

Finding the correlation,
`corrData = data.corr(method='pearson')`

We get,

```
      0         1         2         3         4
0  1.000000 -0.446023  0.304108 -0.136610 -0.674082
1 -0.446023  1.000000  0.563112  0.773013 -0.258801
2  0.304108  0.563112  1.000000  0.494512 -0.823883
3 -0.136610  0.773013  0.494512  1.000000 -0.545530
4 -0.674082 -0.258801 -0.823883 -0.545530  1.000000
```

Masking out repeated correlations,
`dataCorr = dataCorr.mask(np.tril(np.ones(dataCorr.shape)).astype(np.bool))`

We get

```
   0         1         2         3         4
0 NaN -0.446023  0.304108 -0.136610 -0.674082
1 NaN       NaN  0.563112  0.773013 -0.258801
2 NaN       NaN       NaN  0.494512 -0.823883
3 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN -0.545530
4 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Stacking the correlated data
`dataCorr = dataCorr.stack().reset_index()`

The stacked data will look as shown

```
     level_0  level_1      0
0        0        1 -0.446023
1        0        2  0.304108
2        0        3 -0.136610
3        0        4 -0.674082
4        1        2  0.563112
5        1        3  0.773013
6        1        4 -0.258801
7        2        3  0.494512
8        2        4 -0.823883
9        3        4 -0.545530
```